# How can I sort a multidimensional array in Java Script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I wanna sort an array like below by the numeric values in the first column.

```
myArray = [
   [5,"Titel"],[3,"Titel"],[1,"Titel"],[2,"Titel"],[4,"Titel"]
];
```

How can I do this?

Comment: please try searching before asking questsions like this...there are 100's of examples here and other web resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just subtract too:

```
myArray.sort( function( x, y ) { return x[0] - y[0]; } )
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method of array takes a custom comparator method as an optional parameter:

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  if(a[0] > b[0]) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

By using Jquery `sort()` function you can achieve this.

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q03q8a8a/) for your question.

```
myArray=myArray.sort();
```

**Edit**

Rightly pointed out the default sort function wont work as we want to thus solution will be as George Houpis pointed out.

```
myArray.sort( function( x, y ) { return x[0] - y[0]; } )
```

-Help :)

Comment: Put this in array also  `[10,"Titel"], [20,"Titel"]`. Will see that it doesn't work as expected.  https://jsfiddle.net/q03q8a8a/1/